# Auto Renewable In-App Purchase History of my app from Play Store

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, auto-renewing

I am very much new to Android, and I googled but not found any suitable example or tutorial or even guidance.

So I need help or guidance for below requirement.

```
I need Purchase date from Play Store for Auto Renewable In-App Purchase History
```

1) I have two Auto-Renewable Subscriptions (Monthly, Yearly) in my Android Application.

2) I have purchased Monthly Subscription.

3) But my problem is how can we get the `Purchase History of My Android Application from Google Play Store` for every month after Auto-Renewable has been done by Play Store.

4) So, I can send the Purchase Date to our server?

Answer (score 0):

Try `getPurchaseHistory` method in `IInAppBillingService` with following parameter as:

```
getPurchaseHistory(int apiVersion, String packageName, String type, String continuationToken, Bundle extraParams)
```

Where type is either "inapp" or "subs" which you want.

Comment: This is great for getting the latest 1 purchase (whether active or expired) for each SKU.  But it will not show the entire history.  It seems this is impossible in Android.

Comment: For that you need to keep track in your own app